# Warn after the first tag that one needs 300 points to create new tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-experience, warning, tag-warnings

Warn after entering the first new tag that one needs 300 points to create new tags. Don't wait until the user is through filling in the tags and presses Post, before informing him or her that all along he or she was wasting their time, thinking long and hard about what tags to use, when in fact perhaps four out of five might be new tags, and cannot be used yet in the first place.

Note I am not complaining about policies. I am just saying warn earlier.

Comment: It's super clear when a tag does not exist yet: it just won't appear in the auto complete list of tags. So can't see how one would waste time on this. If you notice the tag you want to use does not exist, look for a tag that does exist.

Comment: When it doesn't exist you just type it in and hit space, and there it is, sitting nicely in the row of up to five tags. Nothing prevents you from typing it in, and regretting it later!

Comment: Try it with an account of less than 300 rep and you will see nothing is barring the user from trundling right ahead, and then regretting it later.

Comment: While I agree it would be better to just not let the user put non existing tags when they don't have the privilege to create new tags, like I said, the tag autocomplete is clear enough, and when tag doesn't auto complete it means it does not exist.

Comment: That said, there are edge cases, e.g. user on the brink of getting the privilege, who takes a while to submit the question, and by the time they actually submit it, they get upvote(s) that gives them enough reputation to actually create new tags. So having it check "real time" for the privilege has some advantages as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda many users don't even seem to realize that there is a difference between tags that exist already and tags that are created on the spot, since other sites don't necessarily distinguish between the two.